# How to catch the errors thrown from stream.pipeline API in try catch block in Nodejs v12.x

Tags: node.js, error-handling, pipeline, node-streams

Below is the code snippet where a huge file with uuids I want to read line by line and do processing on it.

```
try {
  const downloadedFile = this._s3client.getObject(params) 
  const userStream: Readable = await downloadedFile.createReadStream()

  for await (const userId of pipeline(userStream, split2(), piplineCallback)) {
    console.log(userId)
  }

} catch (error) {
  console.log('Error should be caught here.')
  throw error
}

const piplineCallback = (err) => {
  if (err) {
    logger.error({ exception: err }, 'Error occured in splitted userstream pipeline.')
    throw new InternalServerError(err)
  } else {
    logger.debug('Userstream pipeline succeded.')
  }
}
```

When there is an error thrown from pipeline API it does not goes into catch block but rather reaches my server index.ts where it gets caught in 'uncaughtException'  event.

I am looking for a way to be able to catch all the stream errors in my class's try catch block as I need to do some special handling there.

Comment: To catch errors from the `pipeline()` within the context of the try-catch, you need to await the completion of the `pipeline()` instead of providing a callback. This means that the `for await` loop has to be refactored into the pipeline as a separate stream middleware. This is straightforward by providing an additional function argument to the pipeline with the loop as a function body.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of how to refactor the for await loop into the pipeline as a separate stream middleware. @jorgenkg

Answer (score 2):

Errors thrown in a `stream.pipeline()` may be captured in the try-catch by promisifying the pipeline and awaiting the streamed data to be consumed entirely.

```js
import stream from "stream";
import util from "util";

try {
  // ... truncated non-relevant code

  await util.promisify(stream.pipeline)(
    userStream, 
    split2(),
    async function( source ){
      for await (const userId of source){
        console.log(userId)
      }
    }
  )
} catch (error) {
  // Catch errors that occur during the execution of pipeline()
}
```

Note that `stream` and `util` are built-in Nodejs libraries.

Comment: The above code result into typescript error: `No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 6, '(stream1: ReadableStream, stream2: ReadWriteStream, stream3: WritableStream): Promise<void>', gave the following error. Argument of type '(source: any) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WritableStream'. Type '(source: any) => Promise<void>' is missing the following properties from type 'WritableStream': writable, write, end, addListener, and 14 more. ...`
I am not sure pipeline accepts a simple function as its argument?

Comment: Unfortunately, the typings for the `stream.pipeline` are incorrect. You may either patch the typings locally (look at patch-package) or decorate the line with `@ts-ignore`.

Comment: Unfortunately, errors thrown from any stream inside pipeline do not catch